An abandoned pressurized irrigation line flowing into an existing pressurized line?
I recently discovered a leaking inline valve (valve seen in lower photo) within a buried & abandoned irrigation box in the backyard that was causing some flooding into our neighbor's swimming pool.  There are two inline irrigation valves being fed by a pressurized line.  This pressurized line has a gate valve upstream of these two inline valves.  I believe that one of these valves (valve in upper photo) was feeding abandoned lawn sprinklers, whereas, the other inline valve (valve in lower photo)directs flow into the pressurized line that feeds two anti-syphon valves that were installed several years later by a landscape contractor for drip irrigation after  the lawn was removed.  The setup is puzzling as I don't know the reasoning for routing a pressurized line (the pipe with the gate valve shown in photo) into the pressurized pipe that is currently routing water from the valve manifold in the front yard to the valve manifold in the backyard with 2 anti-syphon valves for drip irrigation (this is the pipe on the right with direction of flow from top to bottom in photo).  Since I knew that the drip irrigation from the 2 anti-syphon valves in the rear was working fine with that gate valve  closed, I knew that I could cap this off upstream of the inline valves.  However, not knowing the source of the pressurized pipe with the gate valve, I capped off this pipe and also the outlet to the inline valve in upper photo. Can anyone explain the rationale for this plumbing configuration?
]1


I'm guessing someone didn't know where this valve box was and decided to feed the right-hand line at some other point. or perhaps mistook an outlet for an inlet.
